# Custom view not inflating layout when added programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a custom view to a linear layout programmatically.  I want the custom view to inflate a layout I've already created.  When I create an instance of the custom view and add it, a spot shows up where the view is, but the layout didn't seem to be inflated (set the background color of my custom layout to green, but I don't see green in the space, nor the image in the layout).

**My custom view:**

```
public class AddressView extends View {

  public AddressView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.place_address, null);
  }

  public AddressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.place_address, null);
  }

  public AddressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.place_address, null);
  }
}
```

**My custom view layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/address_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ff00" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/house_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My instantiation in an activity:**

```
LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);

AddressView addressView = new AddressView(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
content.addView(addressView, 0, lp);
```

**My R.id.content (The linear layout is the only child of a scrollview):**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/test_house" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.place_address, content);` right after `LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);` and comment out the three other lines. See if that works... I am guess `View.inflate(...)` is just inflating the view, not "filling" `AddressView` with that view.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked.  It's a little different in approach than what I was going for, but it gave me clues to get the implementation I wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually worked around this by extending FrameLayout instead of View, and passing **this** to the inflate call.  I think the view was being added and inflating, but it didn't know how to lay out the children correctly, which is resolved if you pass the parent to the inflate call initially:

```
public class AddressView extends FrameLayout {

  public AddressView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.place_address, this);
  }

  public AddressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.place_address, this);
  }

  public AddressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.place_address, this);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but converting your view to a FrameLayout does not seem like a rigid solution. Do you happen to have the final solution? The "addView" method does not seem to work in my occasion either. I mean the child is added in the ViewGroup but I cannot see anything rendered on the screen

Comment: The key to fixing this was passing 'this' to the inflate call.